# mouseenter/mouseover event in Chrome not working

Tags: javascript

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
signup.onmouseover = function() {
        if(pass.value == passcheck.value && pass.value.length >= 6 && pass.value.length <= 60 && passcheck.value.length >= 6 && passcheck.value.length <= 60 && username.value.length >= 3 && username.value.length <= 20){
            signup.removeAttribute("disabled");
        } else {
            signup.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
            alert("Different passwords or length of username or password incorrect, check again!");
        }
    }
```

In Firefox it works, in Chrome and Safari it doesn't work at the moment. Does anyone know why?

I also used `mouseenter` event which doesn't work in Chrome and Safari.

## EDIT

There's no error displayed when I move the mouse over the signup element. Just nothing happens when I do that which I don't understand.

Comment: Why are you performing form validation at a mouse event? What about people that don't/can't use the mouse? You should use the `input` event on the `<form>` element instead.

Comment: If you put a console log at the top of the function, does it print? Then you can tell if the event isn't being triggered or the code inside the event is failing.

Comment: @D.Pardal I changed it to oninput and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mouseover` works just fine in Chrome (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)

Make sure, it's `mouseover` and not `onmouseover`.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  console.log("over");
});
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```